# How to read a file via sftp in scala

Tags: scala, file, sftp

I am looking for a simple way to read a file (and maybe a directory) via sftp protocol in scala.

My tries:

- I've looked at the Alpakka library, which is a part of akka.
  But this works with streams, which is a complex topic I am not familiar with and it seems to much effort for this.
- Then there is spark-sftp: this needs scala spark, which would be a bit much just to load a file.
- There is the jsch library for java that could do the job, but I could not bring it to work

I am looking for actual working code that uses a library and sftp instead of a plain scp, which I am forced to do. I've found that there are not many examples for this on the web, and the ones I have found are much more complex.

Comment: If you do not even know how to add a library to a project then you won't be able to do anything. And your question is too broad. - Adding a library to a sbt project is very simple, you only need to add a line, you can google that. Then you need to look at the docs of the library to see how to use and write the code. Finally, depending on how you want to run this program and where, you may need to search how to create a fat jar that includes all the libraries.

Comment: @Luis Miguel Mejia Suares: Thanks for your request. I very well know how to add a library to build.sbt. Indeed this is very simple. I just don't know how to do it with a java library -  but I could clearly google that. My question is more for a simple way to do it (opening a file via sftp in scala) without to much overhead. I just added what i already tried to clarify (And to show that I am not asking out of laziness). I can't see how the question itself "how to read a file via sftp in scala" is to broad. How could I ask more specific?

Comment: You add a **Java** library the same way you add a **Scala** library since at the end of the day all are jars published to [**maven central**](https://mvnrepository.com/). The only difference with **Scala** libraries is that they add the **Scala** major version as a suffix in the name _(e.g. `org.typelevel.cats_2.13`)_ that is why in **sbt** we use `%%` instead of `%` to add a **Scala** library, that double percentage tells sbt to interpolate the name with the **Scala** version, for a **Java** library you only need one percentage.

Comment: The question is broad because as stated is the same as asking _"How to build a web server in Scala"_, also library recommendations are off-topic in **SO**. You may get lucky in **Reddit** but again, this kind of questions are hard to answer because it is not clear if you only want advice or if you want the full code.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more specific and to clarify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working example, using sshj:

```
import net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient
import net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPClient

object Main extends App {
  val hostname = "myServerName"
  val username = "myUserName"
  val password = "thePassword"
  val destinationFile = "C:/Temp/Test.txt"
  val sourceFile = "./Test.txt"

  val ssh = new SSHClient()
  ssh.addHostKeyVerifier("xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx")
  ssh.connect(hostname)
  ssh.authPassword(username, password)
  val sftp: SFTPClient = ssh.newSFTPClient()
  sftp.get(sourceFile, destinationFile)
  sftp.close()
  ssh.disconnect()
}
```

I tested this on scala version 2.13.4 with the following entries in build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.hierynomus" % "sshj" % "0.31.0"
libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3"
```

I would not recommend to actually use it this way. Some of these steps should be wrapped in a Try and then some error checking should be done if the file didn't exists or the connection failed and so on. I intentionally left that out for clarity.

I am not saying that this is the only or the right library for this task. It is just the first one that did work for me. Especially the `addHostKeyVerifier` method was very helpful in my case.
There are also other libraries like JSCH, jassh, scala-ssh and scala-ftp wich also could very well do the job.