# Read files from a VM from Databricks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to read files from a VM from databricks.
I am able to SFTP to VM from Databricks driver. However I want to read using spark.read.
I have tried:

```
val read_input_df = spark.read
.format("com.springml.spark.sftp")
.option("host", "SFTP_HOST")
.option("username", "username")
.option("password", "password")
.option("fileType", "csv")
.load("/home/file1.csv")
```

Getting error
NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class.
Has anyone done this successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a library compiled for Scala 2.11 on Databricks cluster runtime that uses Scala 2.12 (7.x/8.x/9.x/10.x). As of right now, there is no released version for Spark 3.x/Scala 2.12, but there is a [pull request](https://github.com/springml/spark-sftp/pull/85) that you can try to compile yourself & use.

Another approach would be to copy files first via SFTP onto DBFS (for example, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66241593/how-to-read-a-file-via-sftp-in-scala)), and then open as usually.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your reply. I am using scala 2.11. Then is there a resolution to the problem?

Comment: What Databricks runtime are you using? Because error definitely says about Scala versions mismatch

Comment: 6.4 Extended Support

Comment: do you have any other libraries attached to a cluster? What Maven coordinates are you using for this library

Comment: I have only one another lib: saurfang:spark-sas7bdat:3.0.0-s_2.12. Maven coord: com.springml:spark-sftp_2.11:1.1.3

Comment: They are incompatible - because `saurfang:spark-sas7bdat:3.0.0-s_2.12` is compiled for Spark 3 & Scala 2.12

Comment: Uninstalled the incompatible lib. Now getting this error. org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: dbfs:/local_disk0/tmp/file1.csv;

Comment: I believe that there is some misconfiguration, or something like this

Comment: It seems many are facing same issue. https://github.com/springml/spark-sftp/issues/52

Comment: It copies to /local_disk0/tmp/ in driver node. However it seems gives an error while reading from it. Not sure if we can provide a path to dbfs.

Comment: Can you try to add `.option("tempLocation", "/tmp/")`, but first do `dbutils.fs.mkdirs("/tmp")`

Comment: It copies to the tempLocation however still shows the error for the tmp folder now: Path does not exist: dbfs:/tmp/file1.csv