# How do we connect Databricks with SFTP using Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, sftp, azure-databricks

I wish to connect to sftp (to read files stored in a folder) from databricks cluster using Pyspark (using a private key) . Historically I have been downloading files to a linux box from sftp and moving it to azure containers before reading it with pyspark. Is there a way to enable direct read from sftp using databricks ?

Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71201351/read-files-from-a-vm-from-databricks/71202351#71202351

Answer (score 1):

To connect to `SFTP` from `Databricks` cluster using spark very simple `Pyspark` SFTP connector to do that.

This library can be used to construct spark dataframe by downloading the files from SFTP server.

Install library on your cluster: `com.springml:spark-sftp_2.11:1.1.5`

This library requires some options to connect with sftp server `path`, `username`, `password`, `host`, `fileType`

**Code Example:**

```scala
val df = spark.read.
            format("com.springml.spark.sftp").
            option("host", "SFTP_HOST").
            option("username", "SFTP_USER").
            option("password", "****").
            option("fileType", "csv").
            load("/ftp/files/sample.csv")
```

**Reference:** [Spark SFTP Connector Library](https://github.com/springml/spark-sftp)