# How to Connect Databricks to SFTP Server with PySpark

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, ssh2-sftp

Is it possible to connect to an SFTP Server from Databricks? I have looked at previous questions/answers and according to the a SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71201351/read-files-from-a-vm-from-databricks/71202351#71202351)

It would it isn't possible to connect using Spark (at least it wasn't possible over a year ago according to @AlexOtt)

Is this still the case?

---

[Issue while using above code, have a glance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71201351/read-files-from-a-vm-from-databricks/71202351#71202351)

Comment: Nothing has changed, but you should be able to compile from existing pull requests and use

Answer (score 1):

First, install `paramiko` package in your databricks and follow below steps.

Run below code for connecting to sftp server.

```
import paramiko

host = "test.rebex.net"
port = 22
username = "demo"
password = "password"

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(host, port=port, username=username, password=password)
sftp = client.open_sftp()
```

Then using `get` function you can the files you want by specifying the path as below.

```
local_path = "/dbfs/FileStore/tables/rd.txt"
remote_path = "/pub/example/readme.txt"
sftp.get(remote_path, local_path)
spark.read.text("/FileStore/tables/rd.txt").show()
```

Make sure you mention local path as above, don't use like this
`dbfs:/FileStore/tables/rd.txt`
Output:

[image]

Then close the connection.

```
sftp.close()
client.close()
```

Comment: thanks again for this solution. You have showed me how to use the GET function to retrieve files. Can you let me what the equivalent is PUT files at the remote location. Is it actually PUT? :-)

Comment: I'm getting the error ```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/FileStore/tables/'```

Comment: What is the code you are using and even path. And why are you using dbfs path when you want to put files to sftp server.

Comment: Hi @JayashankarGS, thanks again for getting in touch and your response. Sorry for my delayed response. Anyway, you are quite right, I don't need the dbfs path when putting the files to the sftp server. However, when I try the following ```remote_path = "/ExtractionFolder/"
sftp.put(remote_path)``` I get the error ... ```TypeError: put() missing 1 required positional argument: 'remotepath'``` any thoughts?

Comment: Hi, @JayashankarGS can I get your thoughts on this please.?

Comment: Is you remote path present in server? You need to give `source` and `destination`.
Source as local file path and destination as remote path.

Comment: Hi @JayashankarGS, thanks for getting back in touch. I realised that I needed to include both source as local file and path and destination. Thanks