# Paramiko: OSError, Specified file is a directory

Tags: python, databricks, sftp, paramiko

I attempted to use this solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76330945/how-to-connect-databricks-to-sftp-server-with-pyspark) to download a file from my SFTP server to my DBFS using a for loop. However, I encountered an error stating `OSError: Specified file is a directory`. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
import paramiko


with paramiko.SSHClient() as ssh:

    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect("111.1.111.11", username="my_username", password="password")
 
    sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
    files = sftp.listdir()
    local_path = "/dbfs/local_path"
    remote_path =/    
    for file in files:
        sftp.get(remote_path,f"{local_path}{file}")
        print(file)
```

I have also tried to download a single file outside the for loop and encountered the same issue. Can someone assist me in resolving this issue?